# Adding TextBlock to InkCanvas

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

for some reason I'm not able to add a TextBlock to my InkCanvas. In my program I have 3 RadioButtons: FreeHand, Eraser and Text. If I select Text RadioButton it's supposed to add TextBlock wherever I click with my mouse (I should be able to add as many TextBlocks as I want). The problem is that nothing happens and if I worked with Eraser before it stays on Eraser even though I selected Text RadioButton. It's like an annotation program. This is the code I tried:

```
TextBlock tbx = new TextBlock();

tbx.Height = 30;
tbx.Width = 50;
tbx.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

tbx.Margin = new Thickness(5, 10, 0, 0);
c.Children.Clear();
c.Children.Add(tbx);
InkCanvas.SetLeft(tbx, x);
InkCanvas.SetTop(tbx, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all you're not setting the TextBlock's Text field, so you won't see anything. And secondly you're calling SetLeft twice, so it won't be positioned correctly.